# How to remove outliers correctly and visualize right skewed data clearly while piping?

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-cleaning, outliers

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Need to visualize clearly this data that is right skewed. This is data from one column in my dataframe. See screenshot.

[image: distribution column of data]

I managed to remove the outliers with the following script:

```
testdf <- IdentifiedCars$ConnectionTimeHours[!IdentifiedCars$ConnectionTimeHours %in% boxplot.stats(IdentifiedCars$ConnectionTimeHours)$out]
```

How can I implement this piece of code in my current code (see below) to remove the outliers correctly of the ConnectionTimeHours column? The testdf script returns now a value ..

```
df_image_CTH <- IdentifiedCars %>%
  group_by(ConnectionTimeHours = round(ConnectionTimeHours, 0)) %>%
  summarise(counts = n())

theme_set(theme_bw())

ggplot(df_image_CTH, aes(x=ConnectionTimeHours, y=counts)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.5, fill="tomato3") + 
  labs(title="Distribution ConnectionTimeHours") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5))
```

column of my data where I want remove outliers of:

```
dput(head(IdentifiedSixtShareCars$ConnectionTimeHours, 10))
c(12.0102777777778, 0.00305555555555556, 6.29361111111111, 3.34416666666667, 
1.43361111111111, 2.54472222222222, 3.86694444444444, 14.3997222222222, 
1.3175, 1.75888888888889)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure if I get what you want, but if you just want a better visualisation you could always add, for example,  `+ xlim(0,50)` in your ggplot. This allows your plot to only show the hours 0 up until 50.

If you really want to remove the outliers from your data, you could simply do something like `IdentifiedCars <- IdentifiedCars[(IdentifiedCars$ConnectionTimeHour <= 50),]`

This code will only let you keep the observations where you connectime is equal or less to 50 hours. By adjusting the 50 hours here you can remove outliers from your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. By changing the x-axis ranges I managed to get a better visualisation. So thank you for that! What I actually wanted is to insert code in my current code that removes the outliers on a less arbitrary way. So in the part of the code where I am piping the data:
df_image_CTH <- IdentifiedCars %>%
  group_by(ConnectionTimeHours = round(ConnectionTimeHours, 0)) %>%
  summarise(counts = n())
I want to insert some code like my testdf code right under the plot in my post.